# «Очень вряд ли» — сочетаемое словосочетание?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> И интересы Вашингтона очень вряд ли будут совпадать с интересами
>   Москвы. Разные у нас интересы.

Цитирую (в остальном, я уверен, безукоризненный) текст политолога.

Answer (score 5):

***Очень вряд ли*** — такое сочетание нельзя отнести к нейтральному стилю.

Лучше сказать: **И интересы Вашингтона едва ли будут совпадать с интересами Москвы.**

В разговорной или публицистической речи выражение можно употребить, но для статьи серьезного политолога оно не очень подходит.

В данном случае не хватает языковых возможностей для усиления наречия без усложнения грамматики, например: **И весьма (очень) сомнительно, что интересы Вашингтона  будут совпадать с интересами Москвы.**

Answer (score 2):

Это просторечие из группы нарочно конструируемых ("мы это будем посмотреть", "не влияет значения" и т. п. "порывшихся собак"), имеющих некоторый успех в разных средах. Конечно, политологу надо быть разборчивей, когда говорит на серьёзные темы. Любую степень сомнения можно и нормальным русским языком выразить ("едва ли", "крайне/весьма сомнительно, что" и пр.).

Answer (score 1):

Вполне допустимое словосочетание. Оно эмоциональным образом подчёркивает малую вероятность совпадения указанных интересов.

Приведу, для примера, цитату из сборника "Вопросы славянской филологии":

> Вряд ли, очень и очень вряд ли, он согласился бы "уступить" свою невесту.

Или вот ещё из книги Андрея Битова:

> ...А ей, ради чего все, — что очень-очень вряд ли, но постарается,
>   может, на денек и получится задержаться...

Comment: Малая — указание на долю, мерность; а «вряд ли» здесь — предположительное НЕ: не будут совпадать, не факт, что будут, никогда не будут. Этих фраз писателям уже недостаточно. Грустно.

Answer (score 1):

В Нацкорпусе нашлось два примера:

> Пока сомневался, пока думал, что вряд ли эта затея удастся, ― ловкое, хитрое, шаткое выстроил сооружение, прямо шпионаж: жене позвонил, что не уверен, но, может, дня на два задержится: «Ты меня не встречай»; матери ― что обидно, но, кажется, его срочно отзовут дня на два раньше: «Ты меня не провожай»; а ей, ради чего все, ― что **очень-очень вряд ли**, но постарается, может, на денек и получится задержаться, но на день ее рождения он все равно остаться не сможет ― какая разница, если они и отметят его на день раньше, вдвоем? [Андрей Битов. Лес (1960-1980)]
>
> Случайные ― это какая-нибудь велюровая шляпа с кадыком, торчащим, как локоть, выплюнутая нашим индустриальным центром союзного значения, или пара девушек, шестимесячно завитых, обезумевших от жары, с ничего не видящими глазами ― служащие или студентки, которым никогда не занять такого видного общественного положения, как у тети Клавы, даже если они станут министрами просвещения, что **очень вряд ли.** [Б. Б. Вахтин. У пивного ларька (1960-1963)]

Однако, по-моему, слишком просторечно для серьезной статьи.